# I Angular 2/4 dashboard Widget component

Tags: angular, npm, widget, angular2-template, dashboard

I am trying to do the dashboard for my angular2 application. So, I am looking for npm package like the below link,

http://datatorrent.github.io/malhar-dashboard-webapp/#/

The functions same like above link, I need to add new widgets, need to drag and drop, resize the widgets, rename and delete options like that i am trying to do.

I researched about these I found [ngx-dashboard](https://github.com/jaumard/ngx-dashboard) these package only related to my requirements.

I am looking the package better than [ngx-dashboard](https://github.com/jaumard/ngx-dashboard)

How can I find the the Angular 2/4 package for dashboard?

Comment: I think that is an offtopic question for stackoverflow -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's not clear, what the dashboard will actually contain it's tricky to suggest a package. You can always choose **ngx-dashboard** . It can help you to start with.

Comment: Thanks. But, I am looking for any other package. Thats my 2nd option. Tell me any other packages asap.

Comment: If you plan to get paid version of Angular dashboard, you can find some cool features alongwith inbuild themes. [link] (https://techpikk.com/angular-4-dashboard-admin-themes-templates/) you can get some idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the npm package "angular2gridster".

Comment: Can you explain how this solved your problem?

Comment: I found the npm package what I have been looking for dashboard with widgets with resize and drag&drop funtionalities.